# Has any player in NFL history been drafted to more than one team?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, draft

Has there ever been an NFL player that was drafted by multiple teams?

How did they manage to do so?

Comment: This question has got a close vote for "unclear what you're asking" - are you asking if a player has ever been drafted by more than one team?

Comment: @PhilipKendall That is exactly what I meant. Not sure it is unclear though.

Comment: Under previous CBAs, there were always threats by college juniors to go back to college and thus back into the draft, but I can't remember any player actually doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bo Jackson was drafted first overall in 1986 by the Tampa Bay Buccaneers. He refused to sign after the Buccaneers lied to him about his NCAA eligibility. They told him that it was okay for him to come and tour their facilities. He was informed that he was not NCAA eligible to play and as a result he missed all of his senior year baseball season. He then was drafted by the Kansas City Royals in 1986 to play baseball. The following year, the Oakland Raiders drafted Bo to play football. So Bo Jackson was drafted by the Buccaneers and the Raiders in the NFL, plus the Royals in MLB.